# Array Foreach Loop Prints Last Item Only

Tags: php, arrays

Why does the following only print one fruit?

```
$fruits = array('banana','apple','orange');
foreach($fruits as $fruit);
{
    echo $fruit."<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
orange
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because you have an extra semicolon at the end of the `foreach` line.  Remove it, and all should be well.

Comment: +1 Good catch. The reason? PHP does not restrict the scope of `$fruit` to inside the for loop. Therefore, the resulting value of `$fruit` (in the subsequent block) is the last value set in the empty for loop.

Answer (score 3):

because of the `;` at the end of the `foreach` loop.

this should be the code:

```
$fruits = array('banana','apple','orange');
foreach($fruits as $fruit)
{
    echo $fruit."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the ";" from the statement : `foreach($fruits a $fruit)`
the php interpreter treats ; as the end of the statement. So that makes the body of the for loop empty. and hence even though the for loop runs count($fruits) times but it does nothing.

Comment: No, the loop gets executed `n` times (where `n` is `sizeof($fruits)`) but the loop body is empty (`NOOP`) so *nothing* happens "within" the loop.

Comment: No problem. I see you have now edited the answer. Good job :)

Answer (score -2):

```
// In smarty
$array = array("Apple","Guava","Orange","Papya"); 
$this->assign('array',$array);

//In view 

{foreach name=array item=arr  from=$array}
    {if $last} {$arr} {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks